# Vscode Launch configuration for jest framework

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

Having issues with my launch.json file for using jest to perform unit test on my API I'm trying to build. This api is part of a larger repository, hence the API folder is not located in root. There is an issue whenever I don't open the project on the right "folder level".

The below launch.json file works whenever I open the project on the SubDirectory_2 level.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Run unit tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "--runInBand"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}

SubDirectory_2
┣ .vscode
┃ ┗ launch.json
┣ models
┃ ┣ apiModel.js
┃ ┗ calculationModel.js
┣ node_modules
┣ tests
┃ ┣ data
┃ ┗ unit
┃ ┃ ┣ apiModel.test.js
┣ package-lock.json
┣ package.json
┗ server.js
```

Launch.json:

But if I open on root level and move my .vscode directory to root, as well as changing the path to the jest module as `"${workspaceRoot}/SubDirectory_1/SubDirectory_2/node_modules/.bin/jest"`. I doesn't work.

I.E.

```
Root_directory
┣ .vscode
┃ ┗ launch.json
┣ SubDirectory_1
    ┗ SubDirectory_2
    ┣ models
    ┃ ┣ apiModel.js
    ┃ ┗ calculationModel.js
    ┣ node_modules
    ┣ tests
    ┃ ┣ data
    ┃ ┗ unit
    ┃ ┃ ┣ apiModel.test.js
    ┣ package-lock.json
    ┣ package.json
    ┗ server.js
```

It puzzles me why `"${workspaceRoot}/SubDirectory_1/SubDirectory_2/node_modules/.bin/jest"` doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error that you get ? Probably passing `cwd` in your `launch.json` would fix the problem

Comment: I'm receiving this error `Exception has occurred: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'root/subdir1/subdir2/node_modules/jest/bin/package.json'`

How would I construct the cwd argument?

Comment: like this `"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/SubDirectory_1"`